# VB.net Gridview DataKeys for information display

Tags: sql, vb.net, gridview

I am trying to select a row from my gridview and then display further information associated with the data from the row. In order to do this I am setting a DataKey which in this case is ID. I then want to access my database and select all the records where the ID is equal to the ID which is the DataKey of the selected row. I am having a bit of trouble with this unfortunately as I am not aware  how to correctly access the DataKey of my Selected row. Below is my code. I am trying to take the value of the datakey and set it as an int, which then in return is used in my SELECT statement.

```
     Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim RegDataConn1 As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; data source=" & Server.MapPath("App_Data/1202389.mdb"))
    Dim i As Integer = GridView1.SelectedIndex
    Dim hotelid As Integer = GridView1.DataKeys(i).Value




    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Ratings WHERE Hotel.Hotel_ID=" & hotelid.ToString(), RegDataConn1)
    RegDataConn1.Open()
    Dim myDA1 As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd1)
    Dim myDataSet1 As DataSet = New DataSet
    myDA1.Fill(myDataSet1, "Table1")
    GVDetailView.DataSource = myDataSet1.Tables("Table1").DefaultView
    GVDetailView.DataBind()
    RegDataConn1.Close()

End Sub
```

http://postimg.org/image/yp3ukwsdv/ Here is a picture of my error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the value of the datakey should be:

```
Dim hotelid As String = GridView1.DataKeys(i).Value.ToString()
```

Or convert the type to integer if it really is.

What you have missed is to **tell the GridView its DataKeyNames**.

To do so, change the markup of your gridview into something like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="hotelid">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I have done that in my .aspx code 
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" DataKeyNames="Hotel_ID">
                    
                </asp:GridView>

Comment: I have been able to correctly get the DataKey value however my code gives me an error saying one or more parameters hasnt been given a value.

Comment: And what is the value of hotelid now? Try `Msgbox(hotelid)` just after Dim hotelid As String = GridView1.DataKeys(i).Value.ToString().

Comment: It is the correct ID corresponding to the selected record.

Comment: As the other answer suggested, change `... WHERE Hotel.Hotel_ID=hotelid"` into `... WHERE Hotel.Hotel_ID=" & hotelid`

Comment: I have done that and am still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Remove the quotation marks  such as ... WHERE Hotel.Hotel_ID=" & hotelid.toString()

Comment: I updated it and also added a screenshot of my error in case that helps

Comment: Change the name of the table from table1 to Ratings

Comment: If i delete  WHERE Hotel.Hotel_ID=" & hotelid.ToString() and run it without that then there is no error and all records are displayed. So the problem definitely lies within that statement

Comment: I have solved the problem. I changed it from Hotel.Hotel_ID to Ratings.Hotel_ID. Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: So that was it.. Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Your query string is not dynamic

"SELECT Service_Rating, Price_Rating, Clean_Rating, Location_Rating, Overall_Rating, Text_Review FROM Ratings WHERE Hotel.Hotel_ID=hotelid"

Should be

"SELECT Service_Rating, Price_Rating, Clean_Rating, Location_Rating, Overall_Rating, Text_Review FROM Ratings WHERE Hotel.Hotel_ID=" & hotelid.ToString

Although this may resolve your problem I would recommend using stored procedures, rather than dynamic SQL.  Its faster and more secure.

Comment: but how can I set hotelid to the datakey from the selected row ?